# I can't assign new values to angular scope variable over loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I really don't understand why angular doesn't working for a simple dynamic assigning to an array on scope variable while it iterate, I have the follow script using angular.js 1.1.5:

```
function assign(item){
  item.var2 = 10;
  item.var1 = 20;
}

for (var i=0; i < $scope.container.items.length; i++) {
    $scope.container.items[i].var1 = 10;
}

for (var i=0; i < $scope.container.items.length; i++) {

    assign($scope.container.items[i]);

    console.log($scope.container.items[i].var2); // 10
    console.log($scope.container.items[i].var1); // 20
}

console.log($scope.container.items); 
//  [{'var2': 10, 'var1': 10},
//  {'var2': 10, 'var1': 10},
//  ...
// {'var2': 10, 'var1': 10}]
```

To be honest, Angularjs isn't clear with this topic and I hope solve as soon as possible. I have tried with $apply (wrapping the call to the function assign) but it like seem that doesn't work either. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Seems to run as you'd expect (the last console.log reporting 20,10) in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n7QF/).  Perhaps have a look at the fiddle and see how it compares to the rest of your code?

Comment: @KayakDave your example it's rigth, but now I realize that exists an asynchronous function that is called inside 'assign' function, that function changes the values ​​after a few milliseconds ... your example convinced me that angular is not the problem, thank u so much!